# How to set network as metered connection on Windows 10 for non-Administator

Tags: windows-10, networking

I want to set my mobile phone's `WiFi` network as a `metered connection`.

But as a non-`Administrator`, I could not do it.

So I tried as Administrator. And for Administrator, the connection is shown as metered.

But when I login with a non-Administrator account, the connection is shown as not metered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To set *all* connections metered, save the following as a file with extension .reg and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost]
"3G"=dword:00000002
"4G"=dword:00000002
"Default"=dword:00000002
"Ethernet"=dword:00000002
"WiFi"=dword:00000002
"Values"="1=non-metered, 2= metered"
```

Note that the last line is just a reminder how to alter this script. Remove any line, or change it's Value to `dword:00000001`, to allow *unmetered* use.

BTW, why set all, even Ethernet, to metered? That causes Windows Update to politely *ask* if you're ready to download files, rather than blindly foisting an untested update on your PC.